# Am I 'allowed' to modify props in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

They say you shouldn't modify the `props` in a React Component. Does that extend to modifying them in the constructor?

Specifically,

```
export default class BookingForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        // am I allowed to modify `props` here?
        super(props);
    }
}
```

To be perfectly clear, I'm aware that JavaScript will allow me to do so, I'm asking if this is a bad design pattern that will cause me headache in the future.

I want to re-format some of the props upon initialization; they won't change again after that.

Comment: What is the point if the constructor only invoked once during the whole component lifecycle?

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean? What's the point of any `const`? There's plenty of reasons to modify or set things once and only once.

Comment: I mean - there is no guarantee it will not be re-rendered immediately after the constructor is invoked and in that case your changes are never applied and effectively lost. So, what is the point of doing something that may never be used?

Comment: @zerkms What?? How can `render` possibly be called *before* the `constructor`? How would my changes be lost?

Comment: I did not say *before* the constructor, I said "immediately **after**"

Comment: @zerkms If not after...then when? I don't understand in what scenario the constructor is called, the component is rendered, *and* my props are not considered?

Comment: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781 "If you want to use this.props in the constructor, you need to pass props to super. Otherwise, it doesn't matter because React sets .props on the instance from the outside immediately after calling the constructor."

Comment: @zerkms Okay...now we're getting somewhere. I didn't know my props would be overwritten. That answers my question then. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To re-iterate what [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) pointed out to me, the answer is **no**, you are *not* allowed to modify `props`, even in the constructor.

`super()` expects the *exact same props* that you were given, and even if you try to cheat the system by supplying something different, they will be *overwritten* immediately after the constructor. Ergo, you cannot modify `this.props`.

Even if you try to modify the `props` object to add an extra property, you will see an error like this:

> TypeError: Can't add property bacon, object is not extensible

So you are literally unable the modify the props in the constructor, even if you wanted to.

However, you *can* set new [JavaScript] properties, e.g.

```
this.myReformattedProperty = format(props.oldProperty)
```

Comment: What if we modify the props before doing `super(props)` so like: `props = {blah:true}; super(props);` my goal is `if props.x is undefiend, default props.x = props.y`

Comment: @Noitidart Won't work. You'll either get an error or they'll be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks mpen! Intersting

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the `props`, not even in the constructor BUT you can modify a prop. Example:

```
constructor(props) {
  // This won't work. You will get "TypeError: Cannot add property aNewProp, object is not extensible" error.
  // props.aNewProp = 'someValue';
  // This won't work either. You will get "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'anExistingProp' of object '#<Object>'" error.
  // props.anExistingProp = 'someValue';
  // However, this will work perfectly:
  props.anExistingProp.anExistingOrNewPropertyInThatProp = 'someValue';
  super(props);
}

render() {
  console.log('this.props are:');
  console.log(this.props);
  // The print-out includes the modifications that has been made to an existing prop.
}
```

Comment: Good to know, but probably not advised :-)